# Unique monomial order in $\mathbb{K}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm learning abstract algebra and came across the following statement in the introductory paragraph on monomial orderings :

> There is a unique monomial order in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}[x]$.

The only obvious way to do so is based on the monomials powers, i.e.

$$1 < x < x^2 < x^3 < \ldots .$$

Although the given statement is intuitively straightforward I was wondering how one might prove it. I thought of it for a while (I did go back several times to the definitions of partial/total order, well-ordering principle and monomial order) but I couldn't come up with a proof.

Comment: It isn't unique. Take $$1>x>x^2>\cdots$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not unique as mentioned in the comments. But these two are the only monomial orderings since either $1<x$ or $x<1$ because every monomial ordering is total. Multiplying with $x$ gives you the natural ordering resp. its converse. Notice that the latter isn't a well-order.

Comment: Thanks! One of the two conditions in the definition I have for the monomial order says that : if $1 \neq \mathbf x^\alpha$, then $1 < \mathbf x^\alpha, \forall \mathbf x^\alpha \in \mathbb{T}^n.$ Here $\mathbb{T}^n$ is the set of all power products, i.e. $\mathbb{T}^n = \{x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{N}, i = 1, \ldots , n\}$. So taking into account the latter condition, $1 < x$ and as you mentioned, multiplying with $x$ gives the natural ordering. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.